# Backbone jQuery can only trigger events on elements in Template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to use the following to trigger functions when a mouse clicked is detected several a buttons on the page

```
    var view=Backbone.View.Extend({
     template:_.template($("tem").html()),
     events: {
          "click button" : "foo"
      },
     })
```

Then I placed button inside the template script, and outside of the template, where it is simply directly generated HTML.

However, it only registers the click on the button in the template, but not the direct HTML button.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to set up custom binding in your initialize function in the view, like this:

```
 var view = Backbone.View.Extend({
      template:_.template($("tem").html()),
      events: {
           "click button" : "foo"
      },
      initialize: function() {
           _.bindAll(this, 'foo'); //so foo's "this" is the view
           $('selector to direct HTML button').delegate('click', this.foo); //so when the out-of-template button is clicked, the foo handler is called
      }
 })
```

Comment: I am just following the Todo Backbone example. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html  They have it like the way I had it when it comes to delegating events. It must be something else I left out. Also, your code threw me an error

Comment: It wasn't meant to be copy-pasted but as a guide for your application. The general approach is valid. Is the error because `this.foo` is passed directly to the `delegate` call? You might need to wrap that in an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly specify the el in your view. Which I didn't.
Because the events{} calls jQuery delegate function. And delegate is bound to that as the root element

Comment: In my case, I forgot the # in $('#app')